# Docker compose failed to execute mongodb script file

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose, jhipster

I've followed Matt Raible's post  https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/06/20/develop-microservices-with-jhipster … and I am facing out to an error when running docker-compose in local machine.

The error shown to me was:

➜  ~ cd work/jhipster/microservices/docker

➜  docker docker-compose up

```
Building store-mongodb-node 
Step 1/2 : FROM mongo:3.4.8
 ---> 917819fa18fd
Step 2/2 : ADD mongodb/scripts/init_replicaset.js init_replicaset.js
ERROR: Service 'store-mongodb-node' failed to build: ADD failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder345385260/mongodb/scripts/init_replicaset.js: no such file or directory
```

#### Highlights

I created the **store** microservice with mongodb.

I ran ./mvnw -Pprod dockerfile:build in **store, blog** project. (because docker:build plugin not exist)

JHipster version: v4.8.0

Docker version: Docker version 17.06.2-ce, build cec0b72

Docker-compose version: docker-compose version 1.15.0, build e12f3b9

Anyone have a clue why docker is not able to find **mongodb/scripts/init_replicaset.js**?

### jhipster/microservices/docker/docker-compose.yml

```
    version: '2'
    services:
        blog-app:
            image: blog
            environment:
                - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod,swagger
                - [....]
        store-mongodb-node:
            build:
                context: ../store/src/main/docker
                dockerfile: mongodb/MongoDB.Dockerfile
            command: mongod --replSet rs1 --noprealloc --smallfiles
       [...]
```

### jhipster/microservices/store/src/main/docker/Dockerfile

```
    FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

    ENV SPRING_OUTPUT_ANSI_ENABLED=ALWAYS \
        JHIPSTER_SLEEP=0 \
        JAVA_OPTS=""

    ADD @project.build.finalName@.war /app.war

    EXPOSE 8081
    CMD echo "The application will start in ${JHIPSTER_SLEEP}s..." && \
        sleep ${JHIPSTER_SLEEP} && \
        java ${JAVA_OPTS} -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.war
```

### jhipster/microservices/store/src/main/docker/mongodb/MongoDB.Dockerfile

```
    FROM mongo:3.4.8
    ADD mongodb/scripts/init_replicaset.js init_replicaset.js
```

### jhipster/microservices/store/src/main/docker/mongodb/scripts/init_replicaset.js

```
var status = rs.status();
if(status.errmsg === 'no replset config has been received') {
    rs.initiate();
}
for (var i = 1; i <= param; i++) {
    if(i!==1)
        rs.add(folder+"_store-mongodb-node_" + i + ":27017");
}
cfg = rs.conf();
cfg.members[0].host = folder+"_store-mongodb-node_1:27017";
rs.reconfig(cfg);
```

Thank you anyway.

Comment: show us your Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml

Comment: Did you install docker on ubuntu linux?

Comment: @MikeTung I edit my question with Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml

Comment: @harshavmb yes.

Comment: In this directory location /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder345385260/mongodb/scripts/ check whether init_replicaset.js file is present???

Comment: @harshavmb this directory not exists. Just `/var/lib/docker/tmp`

Comment: So, that appears to be the root cause. Looks like some docker initialisation scripts didn't run properly. You will have to check.

Comment: @harshavmb

Each execution of docker-compose, change directory's name where it looking for:
ex: 
tmp/docker-builder345385260
tmp/docker-builder104421694/mongodb/scripts/init_replicaset.js:

It seems to be a runtime docker task, concatenating "docker-builder" plus a random number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution. The culprit is **.dockerignore** file. You can find it in `src/main/docker` folder of each application.

**Solution**: remove `**/*` from content of `.dockerignore`

```
**/*
!*.jar
!*.war
```

Jhipster **4.11.1** still has this issue. I will submit PR to remind the official of it.